# android library project manifest file

Tags: android, manifest, integrate

I am trying to integrate a todo app which is open source into my main app. I have made the todo app as a library project and integrated the manifest.xml as informed in the manual...but I am facing one issue.

In my library project manifest file it start with

```
<application android:name=".TodoApplication" android:icon="@drawable/todotxt_touch_icon" >
```

How can I integrate this into my main manifest file because I already have an application name...I have integrated activities of the library project but I am unable to integrate this line and it is not working because of that....

Please find manifest.xml of the library project:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest package="com.todotxt.todotxttouch"
    android:versionName="0.7" android:versionCode="21"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Warning 'is lower than the project target API level' should be ok -->

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:name=".TodoApplication" android:icon="@drawable/todotxt_touch_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_label" android:debuggable="true">

        <uses-configuration></uses-configuration>
        <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
            android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />

        <activity android:name=".LoginScreen" android:label="@string/app_label"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Filter" android:label="Filter"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Preferences" android:label="@string/set_preferences" />
        <activity android:name=".AddTask" android:label="@string/addtask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity-alias android:name=".AddTaskShortcut"
            android:targetActivity=".AddTask" android:label="@string/shortcut_addtask_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
        <activity-alias android:name=".AddTaskShare"
            android:targetActivity=".AddTask" android:label="@string/share_addtask_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
        <activity android:name=".HelpActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name=".TodoTxtTouch" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Task list widget -->
        <receiver android:name=".TodoWidgetProvider" android:label="@string/app_label">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/todo_widget_provider" />
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

The main part where I am stuck is with the application name part....how can I integrate the library project application name in my main app manifest because it already has a application name...so I am getting stuck in that part and it is not working because of that only as it throws run time error....

I have integrated all activities of my library project with their full package name in my main app manifest files. anyone can guide me where I am going wrong...

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, integrating a library project doesn't require to change your manifest. Just create your own project, and open the project you want to include in a seperate project.

In Eclilpse, you can right click your project, go to properites, and check: Library-project. In your own project, you must go to the build properties, and in the project-tab add your Todo Application there. This way, the Todo app is build when you build your own app as well.

EDIT (based on comments) :
You can declare the activities that you want to use in your manifest.
The Application name, is not required in your Manifest.

Comment: "You can also convert an existing application project into a library. To do so, simply open the Properties for the project and select the "is Library" checkbox. Other application projects can now reference the existing project as a library project." - Really, it's all there

Comment: I have done all that...please read that link...I am stuck in the manifest xml integration part which comes in the last para

Comment: You already have the Todo application. You don't have to change anything in that application, the manifest is already there, so all activities,services etc are already defined. Just add the Todo project to your new project, and your done.

Comment: I had solved the problem.....I renamed the main manifest file with the name of the library project.

i.e: In my main manifest file it was earlier like this application android name="app name"

my library project name was com.todotxt.todotxttouch.todoapplication.

I replaced app name with the above and it works perfectly.